# What happens if the mass of a rigidbody doesn't match to it's volume X density?

Tags: objects, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I would like to know what effect does an object have in the rigid body simulations, when the volume x density of the object doesn't match the mass. In most cases the default density is 1.0 in blender!

Comment: I'm not too sure what  you mean, but this sounds like something you could try out on your own easily enough.. Could you clarify your question some more?

Comment: Hi gandalf, I have updated my question. What is the right method when people are trying to do rigid body simulation of real objects in blender. How do they estimate scale of their objects and weight of the object.

Comment: Well, it's more like the density is defined by whatever you set as the mass. If you have a huge object with a tiny mass, then your object isn't very dense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that the mass doesn't match  `density * volume`, it's that the *density* is **defined** by
`mass / volume`.
 Needless to say, the default mass of 1 gram makes most objects very much the opposite of "dense" ;)

To calculate physically accurate values for mass based on measured density of real-world materials, try using the *Calculate Mass* operator in *3D view > Tool Shelf* (<kbd>T</kbd>) *> Physics > Rigid Body Tools*:

[image]